# Regular expression doesn't work in class entity symfony

Tags: symfony, expression

There are two entities: Product and ProductDetails:

```
class ProductDetail {

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Product::class, inversedBy: 'productDetail')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $productItem;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'date', nullable: true)]
#[Assert\GreaterThan('today')]
#[Assert\Expression(
    expression: 'this.getProductItem()->getStatus() in ['not done'] or value',
    message: 'The planification date cannot be null for this status!',
)]
private $finishedDate;


class Product {

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $status;
```

Basically I want to create a constraint for the `finishedDate` to not allow to be empty when the status is 'not done'.
But it doesn't do absolutely nothing and I'm curious if I'm missing anything. Even if I put `value` there and the date is empty the message is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html.

Could you try :

```
this.getProductItem().getStatus()
```

You can use a custom constraint in your case, it's more flexible :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html